# Why would you write Haskell like this?

Tags: haskell

I've been reading some Haskell code and keep seeing functions that look something like this:

```
ok :: a -> Result i w e a
ok a =
    Result $ \i w _ good ->
        good i w a
```

Why is a lambda used? Why wouldn't you just write the following?:

```
ok :: a -> Result i w e a
ok a =
    Result $ good i w a
```

Comment: Have you tried making your proposed modification and seeing what happens?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is [*continuation passing style*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) or "CPS".

So first off, your alternative example doesn't make sense.  `good`, `i`, and `w` are not known at the point they are used, and you will get an error.

The basic idea of continuation passing style is that instead of returning the relevant information, you instead call a function that you are given (in this case `good`), passing it your intended result as an argument.  Presumably (based on the naming) the ignored argument `_` would have been called `bad`, and it is a function that you would call in the case of failure.

If you are the `ok` function, it's like the difference between asking you to

> Bake me a batch of cookies.

(where I have the intention of giving the cookies to Dave), and

> Bake a batch of cookies and then give it to Dave.

which accomplishes the same thing but now I don't have to be a middleman anymore.  There are often performance advantages to cutting me out as a middleman, and also it means you can do more things, for example if the batch of cookies is really good you might decide to give it to your mom instead of Dave (thus aborting whatever Dave would have done with them), or bake two batches and give them both to Dave (duplicating what Dave would have done).  Sometimes you want this ability and other times you don't, it depends on context. (N.B. in the below examples the types are sufficiently general to disallow these possibilities)

Here is a very simple example of continuation passing style.  Say you have a program

```
pred :: Integer -> Maybe Integer
pred n = if n > 0 then Just (n-1) else Nothing
```

which subtracts 1 from a number and returns it (in a `Just` constructor), unless it would become negative then it returns `Nothing`.  You might use it like this:

```
main = do
    x <- readLn
    case x of
        Just predx -> putStrLn $ "The predecessor is " ++ show predx
        Nothing -> putStrLn "Can't take the predecessor"
```

We can encode this in continuation passing style by, instead of returning `Maybe`, have `pred` take an argument for what to do in each case:

```
pred :: Integer -> (Integer -> r) -> r -> r
--                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^
--                   Just case       |
--                              Nothing case
pred n ifPositive ifNegative = 
    if n > 0 
        then ifPositive (n-1) 
        else ifNegative
```

And the usage becomes:

```
main = do
    x <- readLn
    pred x (\predx -> putStrLn $ "The predecessor is " ++ show predx)
           (putStrLn "Can't take the predecessor)
```

See how that works? -- doing it the first way we got the result and then did case analysis; in the second way each case became an argument to the function.  And in the process the call to `pred` became a [tail call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), eliminating the need for a stack frame and the intermediate `Maybe` data structure.

The only remaining problem is that the `pred`'s signature is kind of confusing.  We can make it a bit clearer by wrapping the CPS stuff in its own type constructor:

```
newtype CPSMaybe a = CPSMaybe (forall r. (a -> r) -> r -> r)

pred :: Integer -> CPSMaybe Integer
pred n = CPSMaybe $ \ifPositive ifNegative -> 
    if n > 0
        then ifPositive (n-1)
        else ifNegative
```

which has a signature that looks more like the first one but with code that looks like the second (except for the `CPSMaybe` newtype wrapper, which has no effect at runtime). And now maybe you can see the connection to the code in your question.

Comment: Since you could write `CPSMaybe` with either `forall` or the normal `newtype CPSMaybe a r`, what would be the difference? My understanding of the way you wrote it is that it wouldn't bother you when you are writing the type signature but the compiler is still able to infer the exact type of `r`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 7):

Well, the `Result` type apparently wraps a function, so a lambda is the natural thing to use here. If you wanted to avoid a lambda, you could use a local definition instead using `let` or `where`, e.g.:

```
ok a = let
  proceed i w _ good = good i w a
  in Result proceed

-- or --

ok a = Result proceed
  where
    proceed i w _ good = good i w a
```

Writing this won’t work because the variables `i`, `w`, and `good` are not in scope:

```
ok :: a -> Result i w e a
ok a =
    Result $ good i w a
```

I wonder if the source of your confusion is the fact that `i` and `w` are also used as *type variables* in the signature of `ok`, but they’re *different* variables that happen to have the same names. It’s just as if you’d written something like this:

```
ok :: a -> Result i w e a
ok value =
    Result $ continue index writer value
```

Here it should be obvious that the `continue`, `index`, and `writer` variables aren’t defined.

Comment: Another great answer, and yes that was what was causing the confusion.

Answer (score 4):

In the first sample, `good`, `w` and `i` are locally defined parameters to the lambda expression. In the second sample, they are free variables. I would expect the second sample to fail with an error saying that those identifiers are not in scope. `Result` apparently is a type that contains information about how to use given data and handlers. `ok` says to take the data and apply the handler indicating a good outcome to it. In the second sample, it is not clear that one is even refering to the arguments available to what `Result` wraps, or which names refer to which arguments.